# Searching in mvc3 using MultiSelectList

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, multi-select

I am new in Mvc3 my problem is when i simply create MultiSelectList from the data base its working fine but i want to search on the basis of MultiSelectList selected values i cant handle how to do this
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc

using above link i am able to create MultiSelectList

kindly help me how to search records on the basis of selected values from MultiSelectList
my question is that should i create another View to fetch record from database but problem is what will be the database query to select records

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the sample source code, you can see that they load the list of countries into a multiselectlist:

```
public ActionResult MultiCountryVM() { 
    return View(new CountryViewModel()); 
} 

public ActionResult MultiSelectCountry() { 
    ViewBag.Countrieslist = GetCountries(null); 
    return View(); 
} 

private MultiSelectList GetCountries(string[] selectedValues) { 
    List<Country> Countries = new List<Country>() 
    { 
        new Country() { ID = 1, Name= "United States" }, 
        new Country() { ID = 2, Name= "Canada" }, 
        new Country() { ID = 3, Name= "UK" }, 
        new Country() { ID = 4, Name= "China" }, 
        new Country() { ID = 5, Name= "Japan" } 
    }; 

    return new MultiSelectList(Countries, "ID", "Name", selectedValues); 
}
```

Then on the form post they store the selected values into the ViewBag:

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult MultiSelectCountry(FormCollection form) { 
    ViewBag.YouSelected = form["Countries"]; 
    string selectedValues = form["Countries"]; 
    ViewBag.Countrieslist = GetCountries(selectedValues.Split(',')); 
    return View(); 
}
```

It looks like they are putting it into a ViewBag so they can pass it to the MultiCountryVM view, and not actually doing any query with the data. If you wanted to do a query, you would just create a LINQ query using an appropriate context, which you'd also have to write since they only have context for the music entities.